# powershell in vscode pastes clipboard content on pressing 'w'

Tags: powershell, ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm not sure how that happened. I tried to create script, to work with some legacy solutions:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter pass"
stty -echo
trap 'stty echo' EXIT
read pass
stty echo
trap - EXIT
echo "Nice!"

command="
cd /home/user/work_dir &&
export GIT_PASSWORD=${pass} &&
do_some_stuff
"
ssh root@some_host ${command}
```

Unfortunately, I had to pass password through environment variable. I only hoped that shell with that variable will not live long. Also I wanted to execute this script like VS Code Task like this:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Do_stuff",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${workspaceFolder}\\.vscode\\do_stuff.sh"
    }
]
```

And I've achieved some success. BUT, now every time I hit 'w' key in VSCode powershell, instead of printing 'w', it pastes the content of clipboard. I tried to restart shell, restart VSCode and restart whole computer. Also, Windows powershell outside of VSCode works just fine.

Now when I need to work there, I copy 'w' symbol into clipboard, but it would be nice to have more permanent solution.

Comment: Now I've rewrite the whole thing without script, using only tasks and built-in input. But the problem with 'w' is still a thing.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to go and check/repair the [KeyBindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_detecting-keybinding-conflicts)

Comment: Seems, like Theo is right! I still don't understand how is this possible...did it changed with last update, did I messed up bindings somehow or was I working the whole time without using the 'w' letter...

Answer (score 0):

As Theo pointed out, my key mapping was messed up. I deleted that particular mapping and now everything works just fine, though how that happened is still a mystery. My best guess is that new mapping was added to VSCode (inseders) in the last update. But I failed to find any evidence in release notes.